# Would someone clarify the HD section in the Zombie Bestiary entry?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm mostly confused by the line "Drop HD gained by class levels (minimum of 1) and change racial HD to d8s."

Now, let me see if I understood that correctly;

If I'm dealing with something that has no class levels, like an Owlbear, which has hp: (5d10+20), it would now be a zombie with hp: (7d8+20).  Not sure if that 20 goes there or not though.

How would I deal with a character that has 1 or more class HDs?  For the skeleton template it just says to drop them all and use only the racial HD, make them d8s, and if it has none to just do 1d8, which is pretty clear.

I'm confused by the "(minimum of 1)" part though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that you remove HD from class levels, to a minimum of 1. So if you have a level 10 Human fighter, that character has 10 HD from class levels (and 0 from racial). So you remove all of those HD except 1.

That means our level 10 Human Fighter becomes a [zombie](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/zombie) with 1 HD (the one we kept as the minimum), +1 HD for being medium size. It's a 2 HD zombie.

Zombie's don't have a CON score, and use their Charisma for HP. They also gain Charisma 10, so they don't get bonus HP from that. Finally, they gain Toughness as a bonus feat, so your Zombie's HP is 2d8+3.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  For a creature that has a standard HP of something like (5d10+20), would you still keep the +20 or drop that part?

Comment: @Nerevar The +20 is from the creature's CON bonus. You'd recalculate using it's new stats. It'd become +0 from a 10 CHA (zombies don't have CON), and then add the value of the Toughness feat. For the 7d8 version, that would be +7 HP unless it's getting a CHA bonus from somewhere.